# Raid 1 on 2 4TB HDD

Tags: raid

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying my best to learn as much as I can for a new UNIFI NVR project that I am working on for a customer. I am planing to have 60G SSD on Ubuntu server as a bootable drive and 2 4TB mechanic drives for data only (to save NVR videos on it) as RAID 1. However, I am not sure how to create RAID 1 on the 2 4TB HDDs. Please help, if you can.

Thanks,